# If found in object, use another property in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have this Object:

```
Object ->

Content: <h1>some html</h1>
Url : A url
```

Now i'm using this code to work out if a certain URL exists in the current object:

```
var inURLArray = function(url, array) {
        for(var i in array) {
            if(array[i].url && array[i].url == url)
                return true;
            }
                return false;
        };
```

So i pass it the url i'm looking for and the object i'm looking in. I can then do `var found = inURLArray('http://google.com', tabArray);` what could i do if i find the URL i'm looking for to get the content in the same Object. The array is called tabArray. I'm using jQuery/Javascript!

I should say, i dont really mind how i access the content, ie. if its stored in a variable or alerted!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: err can't you do `tabArray.Content`?? I think I'm missing something. Your question could do with making slightly clearer :)

Comment: so you want to get the content from objects matching the given url? or am I missing something? if so, why not return content in your function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the boolean function by one that simply returns the object found, or null if there isn't one:

```
var findInArrayByUrl = function(url, array) 
{
    for(var i in array) 
    {
        if(array[i].url && array[i].url == url)
        {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
function getObjectInArrayByUrl (url, arr) {
    var i
        , obj
        , arrLength = arr.length;

    // loop the array
    for (i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        // store the object in a var to save lookups
        obj = arr[i];

        // if obj.url isn't present or doesn't match, skip
        if (!('url' in obj) || obj.url != url) {
            continue;
        }

        // otherwise return the matching object
        return obj;
    }

    // otherwise return fail
    return null;
};
```